# Delete table rows with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using AJAX to remove specific rows from jQuery Datatable. These rows have value 0 in the 10th column (if we start counting from 0). Below you can see my code. For some reason, it does not remove any row. I checked the value of aData[10] => it is definetely equal to 0 in some rows.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#newspaper-b').dataTable({
          "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
          "aaSorting":[[4, "asc"]],
          "aoColumns": [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
                        {"bSearchable": true, "bVisible": false},null,null],
          "bJQueryUI":true,
          'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                if(aData[10]=="0"){
                    $(nRow).remove();
                }
                return nRow;
            }
          });
```

UPDATE

When I do this:

```
'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                      var r=confirm(aData[10]);
                  if (parseInt(aData[10], 10) === 0) {
                        $(nRow).remove();
                    }
                    return nRow;
                }
```

...then I can see that one of rows has 0.
But when I do this:

```
'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                  if (parseInt(aData[10], 10) === 0) {
var r=confirm(aData[10]);
                        $(nRow).remove();
                    }
                    return nRow;
            }
```

...then alert JS message (i.e. `var r=confirm(aData[10])`) does not appear, which means that IF statement returns false. BUT WHY???

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: At a guess, the value in those rows is 0 with leading/trailing whitespace - try `if (aData[10].replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '') === "0") { //...`

Comment: In MySQL DB this column has value smallint(6). I checked your assumption. No result. That's a mistery. I have no idea anymore.

Comment: Can you show what happens if you change the `confirm()` in you first edit example to `confirm(aData[10] + (typeof aData[10]));`

Comment: @ DaveRandom: It outouts: 1, string. Unfortunately I cannot post Alert Box image as I'm a new user, but I guess this info (1,string) is enough.

Comment: It says `1`? I though it said `0`?

Comment: Oh,sorry. It says 0,string. Sorry for mistyping. Just I get multiple Alert Boxes as I have many rows in my table, and some of them have 0.string, while other have 1,string. Both of these types of rows are visible, none of them is deleted, altough 0s should have been removed.

Comment: And if I put this confirm(aData[10] + (typeof aData[10])); INSIDE the IF statement, it does not pop-up.

Comment: Is there any way we can have a look at a sample page?

Comment: It's on the localhost. Well, I see it's impossible to resolve this problem here, because there migth be something else wrong in my code that you can't see.

Comment: It does seem very odd this, what you describe is in direct contradiction of the rules of Javascript... If there is any way we can have a look at the page we might be able to help further, but I  can't think of anything else to suggest... sorry :-(

Comment: Having said that, what does `aData[10].length` show? Also, what charset do you use on the server? Is charset of the data in the table the same as the one your writing the JS in?

Answer (score 0):

This may possibly be a typing issue. Try converting the column value to an integer like this:

```
if (parseInt(aData[10], 10) === 0) {
    $(nRow).remove();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `if (!aData[10])`? I think the type coercion implied by `==` means that your code would be more restrictive than the OP's, not less...

Comment: @DaveRandom: No-no, it's not if (!aData[10]). That's for sure. I can see it very clearly:)